rbenv: can't install ruby 2.1.0 after upgrading to MacOS Sonoma 14 from Big Sur
I have a legacy application that uses ruby 2.1.0 and
$ rbenv install 2.1.0
worked fine in BigSur.
However after updating to MacOS 14.4.1 Sonoma from Big Sur 11 I can't get it to work.
I've replaced the old rbenv version with a clean git install with to success
$ rbenv -v
rbenv 1.2.0-87-ge8b7a27

I've installed the XCode command tools after upgrading to Sonoma.
I'm using MacPorts, and I've reinstalled all my ports as per their instructions.
$ uname -a
Darwin xoco6p.local 23.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.4.0: Fri Mar 15 00:11:05 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.101.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ rbenv install 2.1.0
==> Installing yaml-0.1.6...
-> ./configure "--prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0"
-> make -j 12
-> make install
==> Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /Users/jose/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0
==> Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
-> ./config "--prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/openssl" "--openssldir=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/openssl/ssl" zlib-dynamic no-ssl3 shared no-ssl2 no-krb5
-> make -j 12

BUILD FAILED (macOS 14.4.1 on x86_64 using ruby-build 20240416)

You can inspect the build directory at /Users/jose/MyTemp/ruby-build.20240424214638.52529.gppzyT
See the full build log at /Users/jose/MyTemp/ruby-build.20240424214638.52529.log

The log file shows that it failed to configure the openssl make file:
$ less /Users/jose/MyTemp/ruby-build.20240424214638.52529.log
.........
 ==> Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /Users/jose/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0
cd /Users/jose/MyTemp/ruby-build.20240424214638.52529.gppzyT
-> tar xzf openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz
cd /Users/jose/MyTemp/ruby-build.20240424214638.52529.gppzyT/openssl-1.0.2u
==> Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
-> ./config "--prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/openssl" "--openssldir=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/openssl/ssl" zlib-dynamic no-ssl3 shared no-ssl2 no-krb5
Operating system: i686-apple-darwinDarwin Kernel Version 23.4.0: Fri Mar 15 00:11:05 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.101.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64
WARNING! If you wish to build 64-bit library, then you have to
         invoke './Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc' *manually*.
Configuring for darwin-i386-cc
.........
  "_time", referenced from:
      _CRYPTO_dbg_malloc in libcrypto.a(mem_dbg.o)
      _bnrand in libcrypto.a(bn_rand.o)
      _RAND_poll in libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o)
      _ASN1_TIME_diff in libcrypto.a(a_time.o)
      _X509_cmp_time in libcrypto.a(x509_vfy.o)
      _X509_time_adj in libcrypto.a(x509_vfy.o)
      _X509_gmtime_adj in libcrypto.a(x509_vfy.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: _X509_cmp_time, _TS_TST_INFO_set_time , _X509_time_adj , _X509_STORE_CTX_set_time , _err_clear_last_constant_time , _TS_RESP_CTX_set_time_cb , _PKCS7_add0_attrib_signing_time , _X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_time , _ASN1_UTCTIME_cmp_time_t , _X509_time_adj_ex , _TS_TST_INFO_get_time , _X509_cmp_current_time )
  "_vfprintf", referenced from:
      _OPENSSL_showfatal in libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [link_a.darwin] Error 1
make[3]: *** [do_darwin-shared] Error 2
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
external command failed with status 2

It appears that it fails to configure for x86_64, and continues with i386.
Can you please help my out on how to install ruby 2.1.0 using rbenv?
Best,
Jose Ambros-Ingerson

What is the output of the following command on your machine?
openssl version

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024)

This is a pretty annoying one to hunt down but I believe this is an issue with the latest OpenSSL version.. very similar to what I was experiencing with different versions in rvm
rvm install 2.1.0 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)
Try rbenv install with the extra --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)
More info on rbenv specific options

Well, your answer is just wrong. Homebrew installs OpenSSL 3.0  by default whose path will also be returned by brew --prefix openssl. Ruby 2.1 is not compatible with OpenSSL 3.0  (it support at most OpenSSL 1.0.2) and thus will not work when compiled against it.

Following the idea from Dan Bradbury I found the solution:
$ CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/opt/local/libexec/openssl10 rbenv install 2.1.0 --verbose

Thanks all for your responses. I'll upvote Dan's response.
